# How can I find the N number of an old flight?

Tags: airlines, aircraft, flight-data

I want to know a **FREE** way I can find the N number of a flight. I want to know the N number of UAL 2258 from **June 19, 2021.**

Comment: By "N number" do you mean the [registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration) number of the aircraft?

Comment: https://www.flightradar24.com/ should have that data, and offers a 7-day free trial.  (I'm not affiliated.)